# JMeter - loop controller with variable loop count

Tags: loops, jmeter

I am using JMeter and I want to define one loop controller. In this loop I want to define the loop count with a Jmeter variable. Is this posible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello, was answer below the right one, if not which one is it ? Thanks

Comment: The correct one is https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852314/460802

Answer (score 19):

I know is very late to help you, but it can help the others.

One good way to do this is to define a [counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) inside the loop controller.

Example, if you want a loop with 20 iterations, you put 20 in the loop controller and in the counter you put from  0 - 19. In the counter you can also define an increment. The output variable is named in the `Reference Name` field.

[image: loop controller with counter]

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it's possible.

Define your user variable using the [User Defined Variables component](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables), or use the [CSV component](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Then, in the Loop Controller, define loop count to: ${nameOfVar}

Since version 4.0 of JMeter, there is an easier way:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller

JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named

> __jm__Name of your element__idx

So for example, if your Loop Controller is named LC, then you can access the looping index through ${__jm__LC__idx}. Index starts at 0

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: Too complicated

Comment: Yes, that's why Philippe M. member of our team introduced the way you mention https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61802. I updated this answer which is pre 4.0 :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following inside the "Loop Count" field:

`${myVar}`

e.g. for a random count:

`${__groovy(java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(128L),)}`

You can access the current loop index (starts at 0) via `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` where `Loop Controller` is the name of your loop.

Comment: I gave you +1 since it's correct, WITHOUT even using the groovy script which does nothing here