# how to use variable in jmeter like counter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm using loop controller inside the jmeter script, and I'm not able to fetch previous variable value in pre-processor beanshell.

Example:

```
var temp = 1; log.info("before : "+temp.toString()); temp++; prev.put("t",temp.toString());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're trying.

Comment: var temp = 1;
log.info("before : "+temp.toString());
temp++;
prev.put("t",temp.toString());

Comment: prev gives access to the previous SampleResult (if any). here, which value you want to access? temp variable to get loop count?

Comment: refer the following answers which may solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847557/jmeter-loop-controller-with-variable-loop-count

Comment: yes , I want to access that temp variable...

Comment: temp will get refreshed every time for every loop count

Comment: beanshell preprocessor does not save the state, so though you use initialize the value, it is like redefining it.

Comment: Is temp value is like loop count? i.e., to know which iteration in?

Answer (score 3):

**To save values b/w iterations:**

Following is one of the ways to store and retrieve the values b/w iterations:

```
log.info("temp prev value " + vars.get("temp")); // first iteration returns null
vars.put("temp","something"); // store or override the value, so it will be available in next iterations.
```

**To know iteration number:**

If your need is to know the iteration number, then use Counter:

[image]

In beanshell preprocessor, access using reference name (counter) as shown below:

[image]

Comment: which solution did you try? storing value? or to know iteration number? please share the screen shots of view results tree and BeanShell Preprocessor.