# Extract objects in jmeter loop then query them in subsequent call

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

Using Jmeter, I am running a script where I make a POST request, receive an object ID in the response, and then DELETE that object ID in a subsequent request. This works when using the JSON extractor and executing the script once, but I want to be able to do this with any number of loops through the script (i.e. successfully POST 40 times and then DELETE 40 times).

The most obvious solution seems to be to push each of those response objects to an array and then loop through, but I've had difficulty doing that- i.e., following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847557/jmeter-loop-controller-with-variable-loop-count), I'm not sure how to then iterate through that object. Trying to embed the index of the loop controller -- `${ids[${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}]}` -- results in an error.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to send the same POST request 40 times with a different body? How does the body change? How do you assert the response?

Comment: @ycr sorry. We send the same POST 40 times, which returns a unique ID in the response body each time. We assert that the response code is 200 or else the test will fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) looking like:

```
ids1=foo
ids2=bar
ids3=baz
etc.
```

and want to iterate them using [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller%20)'s built-in JMeter Variable  `__jm__Loop Controller__idx` you need to do this a little bit differently:

1. The `__jm__Loop Controller__idx` variable starts from zero so you need to add `1` to the initial value, it can be done using [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)
2. In order to get "combined" value of `ids+__jm__Loop Controller__idx+1` you need to wrap everything in [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)

   Full expression would be something like: `${__V(ids${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}`

   More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop over a `Sampler` extract something from the loop and then use it in a consecutive loop, the best option would be to use a `Loop Controller` with a `For Each controller`.

**Using a `Loop Controller` and a `For Each Controller`**

1. Add your `Loop Controller`. Then we need to count the iterations hence add a `Counter` config element to your `Loop Controller`.

[image]

2. Then add your request and then you can add your `Post Processor` to extract a value from the response. Here I'm using a `JSON Extractor`. I'll be extracting a Property from the response body and adding it to a Jmeter property called `objectId_<CURRENT_ITR_ID>`. Make sure you append the index to your extracted variable starting from index 1. After the loop your variables will have values like those shown below.

```
objectId_1 = 1234
objectId_2 = 5678
objectId_3 = 7856
.
.
.
objectId_40 = 56865
```

Inorder to append the current counter you can use the following as the Name.

```
objectId_${counter}
```

[image]

3. Next add your `Foreach Controller` and add the input variable prefix as 'objectId'

[image]

Comment: I know how to make a request loop. The question is how to extract something from *each iteration* through the loop and then use it in a subsequent request loop.

Comment: @dsp I have edited the answer. Please have a look.